# Sono nel / al / da ristorante messicano Zapata

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, prepositions

Alla domanda:

> In che ristorante sei?

Quale tra le seguenti è la frase corretta da usare come risposta?

> - Sono nel ristorante messicano Zapata.
> - Sono nel Zapata.
> - Sono da Zapata.
> - Sono al Zapata.
> - Sono al ristorante messicano Zapata.

Comment: I mean I am inside the restaurant and I'm eating something in this restaurant. What is the difference between the sentences I wrote?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Sono nel ristorante messicano Zapata.

"I'm in / inside the Mexican restaurant Zapata.";

It's not wrong, but it focuses more on the fact that you're inside the restaurant than on the fact that you're at the restaurant having dinner;

It would be good to tell the listener where you're at if e.g. you lost each other and you're unable to regroup.

> Sono nel Zapata.

"I'm in / inside the Zapata.";

This is definetly wrong.

> Sono da Zapata.
>   Sono al Zapata.

"I'm at Zapata's."

"I'm at the Zapata (?)"

These are quite similar; the first one is the equivalent of the English "I'm at X's place" or "I'm at X's"; the second one requires the listener to know what Zapata is already, because "(?)" might be almost anything and is implied; in this case what is implied is "restaurant" ("Sono al (ristorante) Zapata").

> Sono al ristorante messicano Zapata.

"I'm at the Mexican restaurant Zapata."

This is perfect to tell the listener where you're at in case Zapata is not a place which the speaker is familiar with.